# Is it possible to upload a file to <input type="file"> without clicking the "choose file" button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Due to some reason, I would like to upload a file, lets say an image from [url](https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/jcr_content/main-pars/image/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_intro.jpg) or a base64 string of photo, to the  element with java script only. I would like to add this picture to the element automatically when my client preform some action. Is it possible to add a file without my client pressing the "choose file" button? I would like to keep the  element. Submitting the file to server is not the difficulty.
Should I do something like e.target.files/document.queryselector(id of input).files = (file path or the base64 string) ?

Comment: You mean, you want to upload my \user\passwords.dat without me selecting it? You can add a dynamically generated file on the client, but not a file from the file input

Comment: @mplungjan — They did say that file was an image from a URL or a base64 string.

Comment: And I said, you cannot get that from a file input field - they need a blob or so

Comment: What's that _some reason_? What does happen after the file is in `FileList`? You might not need to hack into the Web APIs that deep.

Comment: For security reasons, you have absolutely no access to programmatic fill a file input.

Comment: You could just send that content independently. For example if it is a form, simply learn about [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden)

Comment: @mplungjan that's some smelly jQuery hell you found for dupe.

Comment: @tevemadar There are more than one answer there